# Whats wrong with Codable function?

Tags: json, swift, codable

Following is my JSON:

```
{
   "Books":[
  {
     "title":"book title",
     "Contents":[
        {
           "figure":"Clause33",
           "url":"PressureReleifValve.html",
           "type":"video"
        }
     ]
  }
]
}
```

Here is the structure:  The content might have multiple items in it.

```
 struct Books: Codable {
      let title: String
      let contents: [Content]
  }
 struct Content: Codable {
      let figure, url, type: String
  }
```

Here is the code:

```
guard let books = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Books.self, from: jsonData2) else {
    fatalError("The JSON information has errors")
  }
```

Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: `guard let books = try? JSONDecoder()` => `do { let books = try JSONDecoder()... } catch { print("Error: \(error)"}`. CATCH ERRORS, and read them.

Comment: Yes, please catch the error and edit your question with it.

Comment: You are missing the `"Books"` part, first key at your top level first. Well, it depends on your whole real code and reproducible one. "contents" when the key has cleary an uppercase? Did you add CodingKeys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the model. Use this one.

```
// MARK: - Books
struct Books: Codable {
    let books: [Book]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case books = "Books"
    }
}

// MARK: - Book
struct Book: Codable {
    let title: String
    let contents: [Content]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
        case contents = "Contents"
    }
}

// MARK: - Content
struct Content: Codable {
    let figure, url, type: String
}


do {
    let books = try JSONDecoder().decode(Books.self, from: jsonData)
} catch let error {
    // handle error
}
```

You can copy paste your JSON here https://app.quicktype.io, it will generate the right model for you.