# How to access JSON data from URL in Swift 5

Tags: json, swift

I'm creating a list of data from a JSON list from a website. However, URLSession.shared.dataTask is returning empty data.

I've tried printing outside the function of URLSession.shared.dataTask, JSONSerilization, JSONDecoder, Different forms of URLs

I've been working on this for almost a week and I still can't figure out what's the issue. My main guess right now is that it's because I'm printing inside the function, but from tutorials online I see that they all print inside.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! :)

```
if let url = URL(string: urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!){
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

                guard let data = data else {
                    print("Data != Data")
                    return

                }

                let dataStr = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
                print("DataStr" + dataStr) //Empty


                do {
                    let dataParse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(OuterData.self, from: data)
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)

                    print(dataParse) //nil
                    print(json)//empty data


                } catch let jsonError {
                    print ("jsonError")
                    print (jsonError)
                }

            }.resume()

//Created from https://app.quicktype.io/#l=go

struct Suggestion: Codable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let audience_size: Int
    let path = [String]()
    let description: String?
    let topic: Topic?
    let disambiguation_category: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name
        case audience_size = "audience_size"
        case path
        case description = "description"
        case topic
        case disambiguation_category = "disambiguation_category"
    }
}

struct OuterData: Codable{
    let dataSuggestion: [Suggestion]
}

enum Topic: String, Codable {
    case businessAndIndustry = "Business and industry"
    case education = "Education"
    case foodAndDrink = "Food and drink"
    case hobbiesAndActivities = "Hobbies and activities"
    case lifestyleAndCulture = "Lifestyle and culture"
    case newsAndEntertainment = "News and entertainment"
    case people = "People"
    case shoppingAndFashion = "Shopping and fashion"
    case sportsAndOutdoors = "Sports and outdoors"
    case technology = "Technology"
    case travelPlacesAndEvents = "Travel, places and events"
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "6008740787350",
         "name": "Business and industry",
         "audience_size": 1759626900,
         "path": [
            "Interests",
            "Business and industry"
         ],
         "description": ""
      },
      {
         "id": "6003402305839",
         "name": "Business",
         "audience_size": 1231141110,
         "path": [
            "Interests",
            "Business and industry",
            "Business"
         ],
         "description": "",
         "topic": "Business and industry"
      },
      {
         "id": "6003248297213",
         "name": "Product (business)",
         "audience_size": 935729470,
         "path": [
            "Interests",
            "Additional Interests",
            "Product (business)"
         ],
         "description": null,
         "topic": "Business and industry"
      },
      {
         "id": "6004037932409",
         "name": "Management",
         "audience_size": 323096480,
         "path": [
            "Interests",
            "Business and industry",
            "Management"
         ],
         "description": "",
         "topic": "Business and industry"
      },
      {
         "id": "6002840040679",
         "name": "Music industry",
         "audience_size": 251698230,
         "path": [
            "Interests",
            "Additional Interests",
            "Music industry"
         ],
         "description": null,
         "topic": "News and entertainment"
      },
      {
         "id": "6002884511422",
         "name": "Small business",
         "audience_size": 87865033,
         "path": [
            "Interests",
            "Business and industry",
            "Small business"
         ],
         "description": "",
         "topic": "Business and industry"
      },
      {
         "id": "6003165841322",
         "name": "Distribution (business)",
         "audience_size": 79327710,
         "path": [
            "Interests",
            "Additional Interests",
            "Distribution (business)"
         ],
         "description": null,
         "topic": "Business and industry"
      },
      {
         "id": "6003342222945",
         "name": "Show business",
         "audience_size": 69642870,
         "path": [
            "Interests",
            "Additional Interests",
            "Show business"
         ],
         "description": null,
         "topic": "News and entertainment"
      },
      {
         "id": "6002932439173",
         "name": "Subscription business model",
         "audience_size": 64490740,
         "path": [
            "Interests",
            "Additional Interests",
            "Subscription business model"
         ],
         "description": null,
         "topic": "Business and industry"
      },
      {
         "id": "6003464157303",
         "name": "Business Insider",
         "audience_size": 62085690,
         "path": [
            "Interests",
            "Additional Interests",
            "Business Insider"
         ],
         "description": null,
         "topic": "Business and industry"
      },
      {
         "id": "6003190330534",
         "name": "Order (business)",
         "audience_size": 60961920,
         "path": [
            "Interests",
            "Additional Interests",
            "Order (business)"
         ],
         "description": null,
         "topic": "Travel, places and events"
      },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Off topic but the do/catch around the decoding call is pointless when you do `try?` so remove the question mark.

Comment: Try this url inside [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and see what you get. It seems api is not working properly. Your code looks right.

Comment: `let dataParse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(OuterData.self, from: data)` Same comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58169372/whats-wrong-with-codable-function#comment102720122_58169372

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace

```
let dataSuggestion: [Suggestion]
```

with

```
let data: [Suggestion]
```

The names of the struct members must match the corresponding JSON keys unless you add CodingKeys.

And – as suggested in the comments – remove always the question mark in `try?` inside a `do - catch` block